# How to search for a variable in a text file using VBS

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wsh

Need help with a piece of code I'm writing. I'm new to scripting so please forgive.

Basically in the code below I have `intBusyThreads` increment by 1 everytime it finds the text "Busy working Thread Id=".

```
Do While oTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
  strLine = oTextFile.ReadLine
  If inStr(strLine, "Busy Working Thread Id=") Then
    intBusyThreads = intBusyThreads + 1
  End If
Loop
```

However I only want it to increment if the Thread Id is different.

For example:

> Busy Working Thread Id=0x01 
>   Busy Working Thread Id=0x05 
>   Busy Working Thread Id=0x01

In this example my code would have only incremented `intBusyThreads` by 2 hence thread Id 01 and 05 are unique. I'm having trouble trying to find code that would allow me to do this. Since the thread Id will always change I don't know how to specify that variable. (hope that makes sense) I tried a few things such as `strcomp()`. Suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29) with the unique thread IDs and increment your counter only when the current ID isn't present in the dictionary:

```
Set uniqueIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Do While oTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
  strLine = oTextFile.ReadLine
  If inStr(strLine, "Busy Working Thread Id=") Then
    id = Split(strLine, "=")(1)
    If Not uniqueIDs.Exists(id) Then
      intBusyThreads = intBusyThreads + 1
      uniqueIDs.Add id, True
    End If
  End If
Loop
```